# Shared memory Python, disjoint array manipulation

Tags: python, arrays, python-multiprocessing

I have a complex procedure that I can parallelize. The parallel runs are disjoint and independent. At the end of the execution, I'd like to grab some data about the run in an ordered fashion. Since the runs are disjoint, and I know how many runs there are, I tried allocating an array, and filling it with `None`, and having each thread manipulate its disjoint sector. However, I get an array of `None` instead of what I want. This is just a simplified trivial example:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Array
import math

bins = 1000
buckets = 4 # number of threads
dump = [None for i in range(bins)]

def iAmSlow(i):
  # I return a tuple, my return tuples are usually the same type
  # but there are some exceptions
  # (ie. double array of size 5, vs empty array)
  if i%13 == 0:
    return [], []
  return [k*i for k in range(5)], [k-i for k in range(5)]

def iAmParallelizable(args):
  start, end = args
  for i in range(start, end):
    a, b = iAmSlow(i)
    dump[i] = (a, b)
    print(dump[i], i)

incr = math.ceil(bins/buckets)
starts = [min(incr*j, bins) for j in range(buckets+1)]
arguments = [ (starts[i], starts[i+1]) for i in range(buckets)]
with Pool(buckets) as thrd:
  thrd.map(iAmParallelizable, arguments)

for i in range(len(dump)):
  print(dump[i])
```

Comment: "dump" is a usual Python list which isn't shared between processes. You already imported "Array" so you should use it.

Comment: Read about [sharing-state-between-processes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes)

Comment: @stovfl That is exactly what I'm looking for. I posted a solution with modified code for those interested.

Answer (score 0):

Python's `multiprocessing` has special containers for [sharing-state-between-processes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes). Here is the modified code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager
import math

bins = 1000
buckets = 4 # number of threads

def iAmSlow(i):
  # I return a tuple, my return tuples are usually the same type
  # but there are some exceptions
  # (ie. double array of size 5, vs empty array)
  if i%13 == 0:
    return [], []
  return [k*i for k in range(5)], [k-i for k in range(5)]

def iAmParallelizable(args):
  start, end, dump = args
  for i in range(start, end):
    a, b = iAmSlow(i)
    dump[i] = (a, b)

with Manager() as manager:
  incr = math.ceil(bins/buckets)
  starts = [min(incr*j, bins) for j in range(buckets+1)]
  dump = manager.list([None for i in range(bins)])
  arguments = [ (starts[i], starts[i+1], dump) for i in range(buckets)]
  with Pool(buckets) as thrd:
    thrd.map(iAmParallelizable, arguments)

  for i in range(len(dump)):
    print(dump[i])
```